# Submitting similar work to two conferences

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I have a pilot study that I conducted, the results of which I'd like to present at the upcoming Conference X. I am also expanding on this study so that I not only have additional data, but will also have a broader focus, since my original one ended up being rather narrow.

I'd like to present my updated results (not yet available) at Conference Y several months after Conference X, but I certainly don't want to do so if it's unethical. Essentially, if I were to do both, I would be repeating some of what I present at Conference X (similar research objectives and methods, some of the same data), but I anticipate having further analyses to offer. Thoughts?

Comment: Have  you asked your advisor about  the norms in your research area?

Comment: Besides the above suggestion, which is always valid of course, conferences in most disciplines are not journals. The *same* work can be presented and discussed until you find it necessary or interesting and the community does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly it isn't unethical to present new and improved results at a conference. However, the reviewers may have questions about novelty if your earlier work overlaps too much. But that is up to them to decide.

Just cite the old work in the new so that it doesn't appear as if you are doing a double submission. Then, let the reviewers decide.